# (Axis + Jetty) Prefix auto-generated prefix namespace

Tags: java, namespaces, jetty, apache-axis

I needed to get an old software (which I didn't develop) to test an old equipment. The equipment 'talks' to the server by webservices. These webservices are auto generated by axis (Axis takes a class and make webservices from it's methods).

The problem is: the equipment was developed to read an xml like this:

```
<ns:getReferenceCurveResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.teste.org" xmlns:ax22="http://data.teste.org/xsd" xmlns:ax23="http://util.java/xsd">  
<ns:return type="org.teste.ReferenceCurve">  
<ax21:createdOn>2012-08-16 17:00:59.0</ax21:createdOn>  
<ax21:endPoint>9.2</ax21:endPoint>  
<ax21:fiberId>21</ax21:fiberId>  
<ax21:id>42</ax21:id>
```

And now the webservice is coming like this:

```
<ns:getReferenceCurveResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.teste.org" xmlns:ax22="http://data.teste.org/xsd" xmlns:ax23="http://util.java/xsd">  
<ns:return type="org.teste.ReferenceCurve">  
<ax22:createdOn>2012-08-16 17:00:59.0</ax22:createdOn>  
<ax22:endPoint>9.2</ax22:endPoint>  
<ax22:fiberId>21</ax22:fiberId>  
<ax22:id>42</ax22:id>
```

As you noticed the prefix in namespace has changed from ax21 to ax22 which is generating errors since the equipment was coded to prefix ax21.

I've dug for a solution but could not find. I have recompiled the server side, also without success. I couldn't find anywhere to change this namespace prefix, since is auto-generated by Axis2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything to fix this.

Since it's for testing locally (The server side, is up and running in out client) and since this change would affect only server side, I've managed to change the namespace prefix 'ax22' to 'ns'

You can do that by adding this tag to services.xml:

```
<schema schemaNamespace="http://your.package.inverted/xsd"/>
```

Like, if you have the com.google.something package, it should be like this:

```
<schema schemaNamespace="http://something.google.com/xsd"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

well, its been lingering around for a day so I'll toss in the absolutely wrong way to handle this with jetty since jetty is one of the tags on here

You could use a servlet filter and tweak the response on the fly to fix that namespace issue....but that would be bad bad bad :)

good luck!

Comment: Yeah. I couln't find anything to fiz this. Most places say Axis2 decides this ax22 thing by himself.